# Python Assistance in bruteforce stage of Caesar Cipher with only the printable ASCII character set (32-126)

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, ascii

I am trying to limit decryption in the bruteforcing stage (3) to between ASCII 32 and ASCII 126. I have succeeded in it during the first two stages, but I am having a little trouble with implementing it during bruteforcing so my results come back accurate. The desired output is:

```
*** Menu ***

1. Encrypt string
2. Decrypt string
3. Brute force decryption
4. Quit

What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]? 3

Please enter string to decrypt: ykixkz&yw{oxxkr

Offset: 1 = Decrypted string: xjhwjy%xvznwwjq
Offset: 2 = Decrypted string: wigvix$wuymvvip
Offset: 3 = Decrypted string: vhfuhw#vtxluuho
Offset: 4 = Decrypted string: ugetgv"uswkttgn
Offset: 5 = Decrypted string: tfdsfu!trvjssfm
Offset: 6 = Decrypted string: secret squirrel
Offset: 7 = Decrypted string: rdbqds~rpthqqdk
Offset: 8 = Decrypted string: qcapcr}qosgppcj
Offset: 9 = Decrypted string: pb`obq|pnrfoobi
Offset: 10 = Decrypted string: oa_nap{omqennah
```

as you can see, it needs to produce "secret squirrel".

In the bruteforcing, I do not know where to implement the

```
for char in stringEncrypt:
        x = ord(char)
        x = x + offsetValue

        while x < 32:
            x += 95
        while x > 126:
            x -= 95  

        total += chr(x)
```

so I can also achieve an output that decrypts from ASCII 32 to ASCII 126.

Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried making it into a while loop and also putting it in different places in the code.

```
    print("*** Menu ***")
print(" ")
print("1. Encrypt string")
print("2. Decrypt string")
print("3. Brute force decryption")
print("4. Quit")
print(" ")
selection = int(input("What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]? "))

while selection == 1:
    stringEncrypt = input("Please enter string to encrypt: ")
    offsetValue = int(input("Please enter offset value (1 to 94): "))
    total = ""

    for char in stringEncrypt:
        x = ord(char)
        x = x + offsetValue

        while x < 32:
            x += 95
        while x > 126:
            x -= 95  

        total += chr(x)

    print(" ")
    print("Encrypted string:")
    print(total)


    print(" ")
    print("*** Menu ***")
    print(" ")
    print("1. Encrypt string")
    print("2. Decrypt string")
    print("3. Brute force decryption")
    print("4. Quit")
    print(" ")
    selection = int(input("What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]? "))

while selection == 2:
    stringDecrypt = input("Please enter string to decrypt: ")
    offsetValue = int(input("Please enter offset value (1 to 94): "))
    total = ""

    for char in stringDecrypt:
        x = ord(char)
        x = x - offsetValue

        while x < 32:
            x += 95
        while x > 126:
            x -= 95

        total += chr(x)

    print(" ")
    print("Decrypted string:")
    print(total)


    print(" ")
    print("*** Menu ***")
    print(" ")
    print("1. Encrypt string")
    print("2. Decrypt string")
    print("3. Brute force decryption")
    print("4. Quit")
    print(" ")
    selection = int(input("What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]? "))

while selection == 3:
    stringDecrypt = input("Please enter string to decrypt: ")
    decryptList = list(stringDecrypt)
    offsetValue = 0
    decryptIndex = 0


    for offsetValue in range(1, 95, 1):

    for decryptIndex in range(len(decryptList)):

        shifting = (ord(decryptList[decryptIndex]) - ord(" ") - offsetValue) % 95
        chrDecrypt = chr(shifting + ord(" "))
        decryptList[decryptIndex] = chrDecrypt
        decryptIndex += 1

    stringDecrypt = ''.join(decryptList)

    print("Offset", offsetValue, " = Decrypted string:", stringDecrypt)


    print(" ")
    print("*** Menu ***")
    print(" ")
    print("1. Encrypt string")
    print("2. Decrypt string")
    print("3. Brute force decryption")
    print("4. Quit")
    print(" ")
    selection = int(input("What would you like to do [1,2,3,4]?"))

if selection == 4:
    print("Goodbye.")
```

I expect the output to be, entering ykixkz&yw{oxxkr:

```
Offset: 1 = Decrypted string: xjhwjy%xvznwwjq
Offset: 2 = Decrypted string: wigvix$wuymvvip
Offset: 3 = Decrypted string: vhfuhw#vtxluuho
Offset: 4 = Decrypted string: ugetgv"uswkttgn
Offset: 5 = Decrypted string: tfdsfu!trvjssfm
Offset: 6 = Decrypted string: secret squirrel
Offset: 7 = Decrypted string: rdbqds~rpthqqdk
Offset: 8 = Decrypted string: qcapcr}qosgppcj
Offset: 9 = Decrypted string: pb`obq|pnrfoobi
Offset: 10 = Decrypted string: oa_nap{omqennah
```

but instead I get:

```
Offset 1  = Decrypted string: xjhwjy%xvznwwjq
Offset 2  = Decrypted string: vhfuhw#vtxluuho
Offset 3  = Decrypted string: secret squirrel
Offset 4  = Decrypted string: oa_nap{omqennah
Offset 5  = Decrypted string: j\Zi\kvjhl`ii\c
Offset 6  = Decrypted string: dVTcVepdbfZccV]
Offset 7  = Decrypted string: ]OM\O^i][_S\\OV
Offset 8  = Decrypted string: UGETGVaUSWKTTGN
Offset 9  = Decrypted string: L><K>MXLJNBKK>E
Offset 10  = Decrypted string: B42A4CNB@D8AA4;
```

(Up to 94).

Comment: This is a fascinating and well written first question, although I think it would help to be more specific with your title.

Comment: Revised. Is that better?

Comment: Looks like you're decrypting with a negative value, at the very least. Your Caesar cipher seems to move in the wrong direction.

Comment: Do you know where this is happening, @MaartenBodewes?

Comment: No, because you haven't shown us the complete code to replicate the issue.

Comment: I had it in a paste bin, but added it to the OP @MaartenBodewes.

Comment: Please create `encrypt` and `decrypt` methods. You first implement encryption / decryption only to retake the steps incorrectly in step 3.

Comment: I have not learned methods yet. Would functions be fine?

Comment: Functions / methods used interchangeably in many languages. But yes, functions :)

Answer (score 1):

Note the difference between your char decryption at the decrypt function (x) and the brute force function (chrDecrypt). At the later, you do not make sure the character is looping correctly. This is where the condition should be, basically making sure you are looping on the values 32 to 128.

One way to implement it would be as follows:

```
shifting = (ord(decryptList[decryptIndex]) - ord(" ") - offsetValue) % 95
chrDecrypt = chr(shifting + ord(" "))
```

This will be a shifted module on the required char.

In order to deal with the overriding of the `decryptList` array, you can do the following:

```
...
tempDecrypt = []
    for decryptIndex in range(len(decryptList)):

        shifting = (ord(decryptList[decryptIndex]) - ord(" ") - offsetValue) % 95
        chrDecrypt = chr(shifting + ord(" "))
        tempDecrypt.append(chrDecrypt)
        decryptIndex += 1

    stringDecrypt = ''.join(tempDecrypt)
...
```

This will fix the change of order you noticed in the previous code.

Comment: There is still a `+` and a modulus of 95 cannot suddenly become 96.

Comment: Almost, decryption in the sample code was with a `-` for the `offsetValue`.

Comment: I implemented your idea and ran it, and it looked much closer to what I needed, but it is a tad off. As seen in the required output, offset 1 shifts each character -1, offset 2 - 2, offset 3 - 3 etc. Is something wrong in my for loop?

Comment: Your loop overrides the original string at every iteration when you assign `decryptList[decryptIndex] = chrDecrypt`, so the next iteration is computed relative to the previous shift. You can either keep overriding and use offsetValue=1 each time, or (preferably) keep the original string untouched so you could keep reading it, and write to another variable.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY:**

```
cipher_text = input("Enter the Cipher Text = ")
length = len(cipher_text)
plain_text = ""
i = 0
key = 1
while key < 26:
    plain_text = ""
    while i < length:
        if ord(cipher_text[i]) - key < 32:
            plain_text += chr(ord(cipher_text[i]) - key + 95)
        else:
            plain_text += chr(ord(cipher_text[i]) - key)
        i += 1

    i = 0

    print("Decrypting cipher text with key ", key, "is", plain_text)
    key += 1
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
Enter the Cipher Text = ykixkz&yw{oxxkr
Decrypting cipher text with key  1 is xjhwjy%xvznwwjq
Decrypting cipher text with key  2 is wigvix$wuymvvip
Decrypting cipher text with key  3 is vhfuhw#vtxluuho
Decrypting cipher text with key  4 is ugetgv"uswkttgn
Decrypting cipher text with key  5 is tfdsfu!trvjssfm
Decrypting cipher text with key  6 is secret squirrel
Decrypting cipher text with key  7 is rdbqds~rpthqqdk
Decrypting cipher text with key  8 is qcapcr}qosgppcj
Decrypting cipher text with key  9 is pb`obq|pnrfoobi
Decrypting cipher text with key  10 is oa_nap{omqennah
Decrypting cipher text with key  11 is n`^m`oznlpdmm`g
Decrypting cipher text with key  12 is m_]l_nymkocll_f
Decrypting cipher text with key  13 is l^\k^mxljnbkk^e
Decrypting cipher text with key  14 is k][j]lwkimajj]d
Decrypting cipher text with key  15 is j\Zi\kvjhl`ii\c
Decrypting cipher text with key  16 is i[Yh[juigk_hh[b
Decrypting cipher text with key  17 is hZXgZithfj^ggZa
Decrypting cipher text with key  18 is gYWfYhsgei]ffY`
Decrypting cipher text with key  19 is fXVeXgrfdh\eeX_
Decrypting cipher text with key  20 is eWUdWfqecg[ddW^
Decrypting cipher text with key  21 is dVTcVepdbfZccV]
Decrypting cipher text with key  22 is cUSbUdocaeYbbU\
Decrypting cipher text with key  23 is bTRaTcnb`dXaaT[
Decrypting cipher text with key  24 is aSQ`Sbma_cW``SZ
Decrypting cipher text with key  25 is `RP_Ral`^bV__RY
```

**P.S.** The code that you provided isn't of Caesar cipher, it is of Modified Caesar cipher. The difference between the two is that Caesar cipher uses constant key (key = 3), but Modified Caesar cipher can use variable keys (0 < key < 26).